# Detecting non-character Unicode characters

Tags: swift, unicode, noncharacter

I'm working on an application that eventually reads and prints arbitrary and untrustable Unicode characters to the screen.

There are a number of ways to wreck havoc using Unicode strings, and I would like my program to behave correctly for "dangerous" strings. For instance, the [RTL override](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm) character will make strings look like they're backwards.

Since the audience is mostly programmers, my solution would be to, first, get the type C canonical form of the string, and then replace anything that's not a printable character on its own with the Unicode code point in the form `\uXXXXXX`. (The intent is not to have a perfectly accurate representation of the string, it is to have a mostly good representation. The full string data is still available.)

My problem, then, is determining what's an actual printable character and what's a non-printable character. Swift has a `Character` class, but contrary to, say, Java's `Character` class, the Swift one doesn't seem to have any method to find out the classification of a character.

How could I carry that plan? Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: "Anything not ASCII" too broad? You can always parse the latest main Unicode data file (usually called `unicode.txt` if memory serves) and compile a few lists of it yourself. Oddities such as "not-a-valid character" and "not-displayable" are clearly marked in it.

Comment: @Jongware, 'anything not ASCII' would probably work, but as a native French speaker, I always find the approach really crude and lazy.

Comment: .. By the way, you cannot consider Arabic and Hebrew "safe to display" but the RTL marker *not*. (Perhaps then only parse it when actually followed by an RTL language.)

Comment: Found it: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt. I've used older versions for other purposes; it contains lots of abbreviations, but is really well worth looking in to.

Comment: You should read [Chapter 23](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch23.pdf) of the Unicode Standard, which describes some of the characters you may want to call "dangerous". Unicode does not have a concept for what is or is not "printable", but you may have some luck identifying problematic characters by looking at their rendered bounding box.